# How to automatically take a picture after autofocus [iOS/Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, image, camera, photo

I'm new on iOS Development and for my fisrt project, i need to develop a sample application dedicated to do this:

1. Launch Camera view
2. Do an autofocus
3. Take automatically a picture after autofocusing

I don't want to push a button to take a picture, it will be automatic.

I don't know how can i do it, I looked for on differents websites and tutorials, the only results were just "How to take a picture"

Can you guide me for the right way to start?

Comment: There is a library at GitHub that can help you. https://github.com/remirobert/CameraEngine

Comment: Thank for your response, i have already test this library but she's not really friendly for me with Swift 4. I have test AVFoundation library too and i have some success to resolve my problem.

I used face recognition for automate the capture of pictures